# IE9 Compatability Mode for intranet sites has the wrong User-Agent String

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, view, compatibility

I'm working in a big project, and we must determinate if the user is using the compatibility view in IE.
I'm using this code to do that.

```
var agentStr = navigator.userAgent;
var mode = null;
if (agentStr.indexOf("Trident/5.0") > -1) {
    if (agentStr.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1)
        mode = "IE9CV";
    else
        mode = "IE9";
} else if (agentStr.indexOf("Trident/4.0") > -1) {
    if (agentStr.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1)
        mode = "IE8CV";
    else
        mode = "IE8";
} else
    mode = "IE7";
```

It is working great, the problem is that:
1 - In an INTRANET environment, the option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is checked in the client's browser, and there is nothing I can do about that
[image: Compatibility View]

2 - There would be no problem for the script to detect the compatibility view, BUT I don't know why, the user agent that I receive is this one below if the page loads on IE 9 **compatibility view**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
```

The very **same** as it would be if the page loaded with **IE9**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
```

While I sould be receiving

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
```

For IE9 Compatibility View.
I get this last result when I FORCE the IE9 Compatibility View (As expected) but when it loads by itself I get just the same user-agent as IE9 standard would send me. So I can't figure out a way to determinate if the user has the IE9 standard view or compatibility view.

I don't know if I made myself clear, but is looks like a big IE bug.
How should I proceed? Has anyone also experienced this problem?

This is the screen simulating the situations:
[image: Compatibility View]

Comment: Very strange... Are you sure it is actually showing it in Compatability Mode with the "Display intranet sites" checked? Because you are right, it should be displaying `MSIE 7.0; Trident/5.0;` for IE9 Comp Mode. Just asking because if the UAgent is displaying that, maybe it isn't in fact actually in Comp Mode.

Comment: mcpDESIGNS check my last edit... I've added an image simulating the situations, and the responses I get =/

Comment: @Christoph This is not a duplicate, but a different issue in itself.  I've been dealing with compatability a lot lately and I didn't even know about this issue. Have you tried contact Microsoft at all to see if they have any advice on this strange Intranet checkbox issue? I feel like unless the UAString is correct, I don't know how else you could know if it's truly in Compatability mode

Comment: I'm affraid the moderators haven't read the entire post at all, or even tried to understand it. The community loses knowledge and the power of solving problems together everytime people act like that.

Comment: **This is not a Duplicate**. I'll try to re-open it rafaces. I even changed the title. Any luck figuring it out? I've been looking, can't find anything either!

Comment: Thanks mcpDESIGNS for reopening the question... I haven't found anything either until now... The problem still remains =/

Answer (score -1):

Compatibility mode is a pain in almost everywhere! :)

However, try not to detect the browser agent as it can easily be fooled and not reliable in general, instead try 'feature detection'.

There are some libaries you can use to do this

- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)
- [hasjs](http://davidwalsh.name/hasjs)

EDIT: if your requirement is to prevent users accessing the site with compatibility view enabled you can use the `<META> tag / HTTP header.` to disable that mode. See here for more information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx

Comment: I know what you mean, and that would a perfect solution, **but** it is a requisite from the analysts that I **detect** the Compatibility Mode and block the access if the user has Compatibility View enabled.

Comment: I'm already using the tag to set the browser to IE9:

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9" />

The problem is that the Compatibility View Settings (on Intranet) overrides the behavior from Browser Mode.

Comment: Outside users would behave as expected, but inside (intranet) clients would enter the page with Compatibility View enabled, even if I use the meta tag.

Comment: Ok, don't want a big discussion as I've never tried this myself, but the link I sent says __The presence of the <META> tag / header serves as an indication that the site has been updated to support IE8 and its value “wins” over whatever mode Compatibility View on the client would have resulted in. T__

Comment: You are right BuddhiP, I also have some documents that say that... http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg but it seems like IE turns out to behave just the opposite way as it should (thanks to Microsoft).
When I uncheck the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View", they obey the META tag and behave as expected, but looks like the Compatibility View Settings override the META tag =/

Comment: Unfortunately the `<meta>` additions always get trumped over either the `intranet / always use comp mode` checkboxes in the Settings :/